# How can I draw textures with JOGL?

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I have begun to learn OpenGl and using JOGL. There's something I haven't found any actual or easy guide to though: how can I draw textures? For example, what kind of code would I need to draw a texture at `(X, Y, Z)` position? I want to use `glDrawArrays()` or `glDrawElements()`.

Comment: I think this is really a "how to get started" question in disguise.  Have you tried any tutorials?  Have you looked for any tutorials?

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou yes, I looked the tutorials. But in some drawing was by `glBegin()/glEnd()`, other used OpenGL 2 or less, and still other did not use JOGL. I would be very grateful to you, if you give me any tutorials about this theme.

Comment: So with "drawing a texture", you actually mean "drawing a textured quad", right? If you want to use modern GL, this means implementing the appropriate shader, setting up the uniforms, attributes and samplers and whatnot. Quick websearches yield some results, so it's indeed not clear what your actual question is...

Comment: @Marco13 I type in  Google next: jogl draw textured quad but code of all results from first page use `glBegin()` / `glEnd()`.

Comment: For me, the first result for `jogl texture example` is http://forum.jogamp.org/Modern-JOGL-simple-texture-example-td4029964.html  ...

Comment: @Marco13 thanks! I went to understand in the code.